# Tooltip vertically off with overlapping data, in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've set up a stacked bar chart with ChartJS, but there are some problems with positioning the tooltip. If datasets overlap (stack) then the tooltip is vertically off. **Is this a bug in ChartJS, or am I setting this up wrong?**

Please see example at http://gknudsen.no/chart/testchart.html

Note that the tooltip is correct at the right hand side of the chart, where bars and lines do not overlap. But on the left hand side (datasets A, C, and E) the problem occurs. Especially wrt dataset E (the line plot).

However, if datasets are hidden/disabled (by clicking in the chart legend), such that overlap is avoided, then the tooltip becomes correct. As an example, try disabling datasets A and C to fix E.

Answer (score 0):

Others are reporting same problems, so I expect this to be mainly a problem with ChartJS.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2609